# How to load external resources using a reference URI in Java XML

Tags: java, xml, reference, digital-signature

I am trying to extract an XML node from a URI reference. This URI reference is generated by an XAdES4j signer, and could reference a node within the same XML file, or in the same folder.

I was hoping that loading the reference would be as simple as

```
XMLSignatureInput referencedXML = ResourceResolver.resolveStatic(referenceNode.getAttributeNode("URI"), referenceDoc.getBaseURI());
```

However this just gives me a NullPointerException with no useful message. Both arguments are non-null, and in a simple case the URI attribute was "data.xml" and the referenceDoc base URI was "/Users/ryan/.../test-files/signature.xml. data.xml resides in the same test-files directory.

The URI could point to an element within a file, so I'm hoping there is a reference loader which deals with that complexity for me. What have I missed?!

edit:

The reference I am trying to load is:

```
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-c6050e36-d9e7-46d9-ac5f-447d1bbb405f-ref0" URI="lote.xml" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the NullPointerException? Maybe its an internal error.

Comment: Could you give an example of the URI that you're using?

Comment: Question, is the URI imported as a link in the top of the xml? if so then it should be accessible as Xalan/Xerces auto imports the references, - i saw that when i did some xsl with seperate files making the whole. - Also if the URI is in the form file:// why not try to create a File Reference and then open it up as a new document?

Comment: The URI is in the form file://, however it has an element id appended to it which would make the file fail to be found without extra parsing, which I was hoping to avoid. The URI is no present in the top of the XML, I have added the element to the question.

Comment: Could you provide your stack trace of the NPE?
If there is no stack trace, then you can only debug it step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total stab in the dark (you really need to paste stacktraces...), but here goes.

I took a quick look at the source of ResourceResolver at:
http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/XML/xml-security-1.4.3/org/apache/xml/security/utils/resolver/ResourceResolver.java.htm

I can see there is going to be a NullPointerException due to a non initialised _resolverVector field in the ResourceResolver, unless the static init() method has already been called on ResourceResolver. Above the init() method, there is a comment:

```
The init() function is called by org.apache.xml.security.Init.init()
```

The ResourceResolver itself does not appear to trigger that call - do you do it ? If not you should try it, prior to using any of the org.apache.xml.security stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understand what exactly is causing the NullPointerException so I would suggest splitting this code out so that you can see where the null value is.

Comment: This isn't really an answer so much as a comment

Comment: Not a very useful one either - it is a single command, where both elements are not null passed as parameters are not null.